# Is there a difference between using principal component analysis and factor analysis before segmentation?

Tags: clustering, pca, factor-analysis

I am trying to segment a group of stores. I have  a very rich data set, including different store and store / category level annual sales, well-being survey results in city level, neighbourhood level demographics,  variables representing  number of landmark points such as number of stores, banks, schools around the outlets.

Number of features in my data set is 307. However it's very difficult to assess results of a segmentation study in this dimension. So I do a PCA to lower the number of dimensions. With 9 PCs I am able to cover 80% of variation. But since PCs calculated through PCA are not rotated, it is a bit difficult to label them with inspecting commonalities.

Can I use factors estimated and rotated with VARIMAX from factor analysis? I think these factors would also be representative.

Comment: Of course. The biggest distinctions between PCA and rotated FA is that PCAs provide mathematically unique solutions, are deterministic and do not include an error term. Rotated FAs, on the other hand, are like regression models without a dependent variable. They do include an error term and are neither unique nor deterministic. One way to think of PCAs and FAs as a dimension-reducing step prior to clustering is that, in reality, you don't care about what the factors *mean*. They are merely intermediate means to an end.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But there is fact that when I finished segmentation i need to label, identify, name the segments created. Thats why i think i need to know what the factors mean.

Comment: I've never found the factors used in segmentation to be that informative or helpful in profiling the clusters simply because they compress so much information. Much more useful are the original variables that were used in the factor analysis, retained in their original metric.